# BracketsStructureCheck and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, formatter, qulice

I'm trying to follow the Qulice's rules "BracketsStructureCheck". These rules in particular say that closing bracket should be on a new line in case if method call spans over multiple lines.
Like this:

```
String text = String.format(
    "some text: %s",
    new Foo().with(
        "abc",
        "foo"
    )
);
```

Is there a possibility to make Eclipse format my code this way?